# Find derivative of integrate square function

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am finding a solution of that function. Could you have me to resolve it

$$F=\left( \int {(ax+b-c)}^2 dx \right) +\lambda_1(a-m)^2+\lambda_2(b-n)^2$$

where $c,m,n ,\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are constant

How to find

$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial a}=?$$

$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial b}=?$$
$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=?$$

Update: Sorry, I just one more require

How to find $a,b,x$ if I set

$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial a}=0$$

$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial b}=0$$
$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** You may first expand the integral.

**Alternatively**, you may observe that
$$
\begin{align}
\partial_a\left( \int {(ax+b-c)}^2 \:dx\right)& = 2\int x(ax+b-c)\:dx\\
\partial_b\left( \int {(ax+b-c)}^2 \:dx\right)&= 2\int (ax+b-c)\:dx\\
\partial_x\left( \int {(ax+b-c)}^2 \:dx\right)&= 2\int a(ax+b-c)\:dx.
\end{align}
$$ Then expand.

Comment: Thanks so much. If I set these derivatives are $0$. Do you think can I get solution of $a,b,x$

Comment: Yeah, you can.${}$

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first problem $\frac{\partial F}{\partial a}$.
I am sure you can compute the other two, since they are very similar.
If the integral boundaries are not depening on $a$ you can interchange integration and differentiation. Furthermore, assuming we are integrating with respect to $x$ we find
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial a}=2\int x(ax+b-c)dx + 2\lambda_1(a-m) $$